# Where to setup product dimensions (width, length, height) for shipping magento 1.9?

Tags: shipping, magento-1.9.3.6, dimensions

Where to setup product dimensions (width, length, height) for shipping magento 1.9 we are trying to setup attribute but unable to fix it, can any one assist

Comment: Please explain in details.

Comment: @MichaelHa, i want to setup product dimensions (width, length, height) at every product page, at the time of checkout page shipping / logistic company API can calculate actual shipping rate with destination area pin code.